# Laravel IDE Helpers not working properly in VSCode inside Models and Controllers

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, phpstorm

I'm trying to start working on a Laravel project and I wanted some autocompletion/intellisense for Eloquent Models.

I've installed `laravel-ide-helper` package from 'https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper' and followed the instructions.

The problem I have, is that in Visual Studio Code, it seems the autocompletion works only for routes (inside `web.php` and `api.php`), but in controllers or models (probably others too) is not working.

Instead, I've tried to do the same thing in PhpStorm and It seems it works correctly in that IDE.

Is there a way I can make it work with VSCode?

**P.S:** In VSCode I've tried to install Php Intelephense (I've tried also without him) and is it not working. I've also tried to disable php suggestions from VSCode, still no result.

**P.S. 2:** I've also tried to install extensions suchs as: `Laravel Extra Intellisense` / `Laravel Intellisense` and I've got the same result (only works in web.php and api.php).

Comment: You might want to try PHP Inteliphense by Ben Mewburn. This plugin has auto completion for PHP related files(Not laravel exclusive). If you follow the correct usage of namespace, use, then it should work without problem

Comment: For Laravel related code, you can try Laravel Snippets by Winnie Lin

Comment: you may need to reload vscode after installation

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I have that extension, restarted, reinstalled, I did everything and is not working. I've tried also Laravel Snippets and it still doens't work.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, lots of reports of eloquent models not working correctly when using ide-helper via vscode but so far I haven't come across a working solution, at least not one that doesn't require editing vendor files!

Have you had any look with this yet?

Comment: Did some tinkering and now fixed...

Follow all the usual steps, including publishing the config file. Open the config file and make sure 'include_class_docblocks => true'.

Replace 'use Model' with 'use Eloquent' at the top of each model.

Replace 'class yourModel extends Model' with 'class yourModel extends Eloquent'.

Reload vscode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).